# My D-star registration is not with a gateway with a call sign, but (REGIST)

Tags: d-star

My D-star registration is not with a gateway with a call sign, but (REGIST). This is the way my registration reads: D-star Gateway Registration (REGIST). I can log in, but it is not recognized on any D-star repeaters. I get (RPT?). Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what "(REGIST)" means, but preferably you should contact the repeater administrator or equipment dealer person who registered you to fix the problem.  If you do a web search for "D-STAR registration check" you'll find several web pages that can look up your registration status, and which repeater you were registered on.

If for some reason the original administrator is unable to help, then get to know a local repeater administrator and ask him or her for help.  (I'm under the impression that it's a lot more difficult for a different administrator to fix a registration problem.)